How to migrate a JSF-2.2.12/Primefaces-13.0.10 (Atlantis) + Spring Framework (5.3.27) app to JSF-3/Primefaces-13.0.10 (Atlantis) + Spring Boot (3)
I have an application developed with the technologies JSF-2.2.12/Primefaces-13.0.10 (Atlantis layout) + Spring Framework (5.3.27) that works very well, but given the aging of the technologies, particularly Spring, and the advantages offered by the new versions, I want to migrate the application to JSF 3 + Spring Boot 3.
When I take the project contained in the Atlantis layout archive and try to add the JoinFaces libraries (https://docs.joinfaces.org/current/reference/), I find that there are many incompatibilities. On the other hand, when I start from a JoinFaces/PrimeFaces project, although I manage to launch the application and create pages, I cannot deploy my PrimeFaces layout (Atlantis). Therefore, I am want to know if anyone has a functional project base that combines Spring Boot 3 + PrimeFaces + Layout that I could use to rebuild my application, or if someone has any ideas on how to use my Atlantis layout in a JoinFaces/PrimeFaces project?"

You have an application that "works very well".  Your upgrade could take years to complete and cost your company X dollars for what benefit?  A conversion like this must be carefully planned out.

Where does join faces come from all of a sudden. Upgrading the libraries you mention shouldn't be that hard (make sure you select the right Primefaces version with classifier) and update the proper JSF dependencies.

Spring Boot is much different from "plain" Spring. You're basically attempting to convert from a WAR project to a JAR project as well. This will indeed require many more changes to project structure and configuration than simply upgrading the libs. I suggest to take a step back and first upgrade "plain" Spring alone. I.e. Spring 5 to Spring 6. Then you can eventually later introduce Spring Boot / JoinFaces after having learned/practiced it in a separate playground project. By the way, JSF 3.x has no value. Upgrade further to JSF 4.x right away (also known as Faces 4.x).

We need some more information to help you further. What exact incompatibilities did you find? Since Atlantis is a paid layout, we won't be able to provide an example project using it.
